# How to convert an array of objects to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    value1: {
      something: "something"
    }
  },
  {
    value2: {
      something: "something"
    }
  }
]
```

And I need to receive something like this:

```
{
    value1: {
        something: "something"
    },
    value2: {
        something: "something"
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
const something = 3

console.log([{value1: {something}}, {value2: {something}}].reduce((acc,x) => ({...acc,...x})))
```

Comment: You could express your gratitude by upvoting and/or accepting the answer :D

Comment: I wish I could, but cannot because just signed up :)

Comment: You asked the question, so you can accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

Simply do a reduce on your original array

```
const data = [
  {
    value1: {
      something: "something"
    }
  },
  {
    value2: {
      something: "something"
    }
  }
]

const result = data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(cur);
  keys.forEach(key => {
    if(!acc[key]) {
      acc[key] = {...cur[key]}
    }
  });
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);

/*

{
  value1: { something: 'something' },
  value2: { something: 'something' }
}

*/
```